# VS code multiline quick open menu

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there an extension or any other ways to display it in 2 or more rows?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VS Code v1.53 got [wrap tabs](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_53#_wrap-tabs). This feature will display open tabs in multiple rows.

Check the "Wrap Tabs" checkbox under `File > Preferences > Settings > Workbench > Editor Management`.